# Local Deployment of React App doesn't load on iPad via LAN on Ubuntu server

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, lan, npm-start

I have a very simple React Web Application built and deployed on an Ubuntu server. The application loads quickly and easily on the Ubuntu desktop computer, however, takes a very long time to load (up to 10min) on an iPad via LAN. (The same results were found with a Mac Laptop). The unique part about this issue is that we are deploying on a local server and attempting to access the web app from a separate device.

Building the app with yarn vs. npm doesn't make a difference.
Deploying the app via NGINX for higher performance also yields the same issue.

The static build is 500Kb.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? It could potentially be related to the React rendering process.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to help with the information provided. You could start by using the browser dev tools too start narrowing down the issue(s).

Comment: Dev tools don't reveal anything, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible, but ok.

Comment: Do you have something specifically I should look for in the dev tools?